# Formatting a date column with various factors

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, modern-experience, json-formatting, column-formatting

This should be simple and I hope it is.

I'm trying to get a date column to format in the following way:

If the date is **GREATER** than 2 weeks leading up to the date, its green

Is the date is **LESS** than 2 weeks until the date, its amber/yellow

If its past the date, its red.

However, if there is NO date input, it does nothing.

I've tried all I can with JSON, but it just alludes me. Any ideas?
I can't seem to do it with the built in tools.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using below JSON, it should work for you:

```
{
    "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/column-formatting.schema.json",
    "elmType": "div",
    "txtContent": "@currentField",
    "style": {
        "color": "black",
        "background-color": "=if(Number(@currentField) == 0, '', if(@now > @currentField, 'red', if(@now > addDays(@currentField, -14), 'green', 'yellow')))"
    }
}
```

OR

```
{
    "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/column-formatting.schema.json",
    "elmType": "div",
    "txtContent": "@currentField",
    "style": {
        "color": "black",
        "background-color": "=if(Number(@currentField) == 0, '', if(@now < addDays(@currentField, -14), 'yellow', if(@now > addDays(@currentField, -14) && @currentField >= @now, 'green', 'red')))"
    }
}
```

**Output**:

[image]

**Documentation**: [SharePoint column formatting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/declarative-customization/column-formatting)

**Related read**: [SharePoint JSON formatting: Check if date & time column is blank/empty](https://ganeshsanapblogs.wordpress.com/2021/06/20/sharepoint-json-formatting-check-if-date-and-time-column-is-blank-empty/)

Comment: Thank you! That did the trick perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

Please try below codes.

```
 {
   "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/column-formatting.schema.json",
   "elmType": "div",
   "txtContent": "@currentField",
   "style": {
     "color": "black",
     "background-color": "=if(@currentField>@now + 1209600000,'green', if((@currentField>=@now) && (@currentField<@now + 1209600000),'yellow', if(Number(@currentField) == 0, ' ', 'red')))"
   }
 }
```

Result:

[image]